# Issue in cjuidialog close and reopen in mutiple ajax request

Tags: yii

i am using cjuidialog for popup a webform through ajax links.
First time it is opening nice.But after close and i navigate to another page and come to this page again without reloading the whole page but reloading a div only through multiple ajax requests,the pop up is not coming.Kindly suggest me the soluton.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that CJUIdialog creates s with popups inside everytime you send ajax request. So after few request you have several popup divs with the same ID. What I did I removed CJUIDialog div and its parent in every ajax request. Like this:

```
function remove_popup(){
            if($("#popup1").length){
                $("#popup1").remove();
                if($("#popup1").parent().hasClass("ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable")){
                    $("#popup1").parent().remove();
                }
            }
    }
```

And important to include:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery-ui.min.js'] = false;
```

in the begging of a view. (not in the main view)